# simple way to lock and unlock in python

Tags: python

The file may be simultaneously read and written by Python. Is there a simpler way instead of using lock?

```
class datamanager:
  def __init__(self, filename = 'filelock'):
    ....

  def write(self, data, isInit = False):
    ....

  def read(self):
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/threading.html#using-locks-conditions-and-semaphores-in-the-with-statement).

Also, the lock is needed only in the write method, as the read method doesn't modify the file.

Comment: how about reading a file which is being modified?wont that cause a problem?

Comment: Nope. If the file is currently written, then the lock on the write method will prevent any reader from acquiring the file. After the lock has been released, the reader can access the modified file. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writer_lock